# How to integrate VoiceBase Player UI code into my React Application

Tags: open-source, voice-recording

I came to know that they have done some open source contribution of their frontend code. Can anyone help me with getting the source code and steps of integration?

Thanks in advance.

[Click to view the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aGGb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted the VoiceBase technical support team and they have given me the **source code and documentation link**.

**Player Resources**: One is designed to be embedded in React / Redux applications: https://www.npmjs.com/package/voicebase-player-react